# Reading csv's into dataframe, change parts of frame, and append all to a single frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with multiple csv files containing stock data. I want to read all the files into dataframes and drop the data I dont need, and then combine the rest into a single dataframe. I have written some code that works, but it does it in a bad way, with some intermediary steps that I want to skip to make it more effective. This is the code I use now.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob


my_dir = "Path where the csv files is stored" #Directory containing the     InFront data files

my_dir2 = "path where I save the csv's after droping some columns, and the   final file." # 

#Reads inn the csv file names into a list
filelist = []
os.chdir(my_dir)

for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    filelist.append(files)

#Open csv files from list and droppes everything but close price from the data frames
for string in filelist:
    path = "%s\\%s" % (my_dir, string)
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=[1], parse_dates=True)

    frame = frame.drop('<TIME>', 1)
    frame = frame.drop('<OPEN>', 1)
    frame = frame.drop('<HIGH>', 1)
    frame = frame.drop('<LOW>', 1)
    frame = frame.drop('<VOL>', 1)
    frame.index.names = ['Date']
    ticker = frame['<TICKER>'].ix[1]
    frame.rename(columns = {'<CLOSE>' : ticker}, inplace=True)
    frame.drop(frame.columns[0], 1, inplace=True)
    frame.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)

#Saves the files to the folder specified as my_dir2
    frame.to_csv('%s\\new %s' % (my_dir2, string))   


filelist = []
os.chdir(my_dir2)

for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    filelist.append(files)

df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True) for file in   filelist]


big_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
big_df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
big_df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

As you can see I have done this in two steps, where I also needed to save the results from the first one. There must be a simple way for me to do this, and I hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: DataFrame.drop will accept a list of labels, no need to drop individually. Why are you writing out to csv then reading in again? you could do df_list.append(frame) at the end of your main loop. Your first loop is slightly unnecessary, just do: filelist = glob.glob("*.csv"), or just change your main loop to: for string in glob.glob("*.csv"):

Comment: Adding df_list = pd.DataFrame() before the main loop, and then df_list.append(frame) after the frame.sort_index part just returns a empty dataframe.

Comment: df_list = [] before the main loop, then big_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1) as you already have.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. Can you explain how/why that works? Doesnt the frame variable get overwritten during each iteration in the loop? For instance if I just write frame in the console after running the loop then it will write out the data from the last csv file in the folder.

Comment: This might be wrong... but I think frame is effectively just a pointer to the dataframes created by pd.read_csv(), each loop the pointer is overwritten and appended to the list.

Comment: `DataFrame.append` isn't *in-place*: it returns a new DataFrame rather than modifying the current one. So you'd have to use `df_list = df_list.append(frame)` instead. (The solution that matt_s gave is more efficient though).

Comment: matt_s that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.